# What is the FastLoad (in Teradata) equivalent for ParAccel?

Tags: analytics, sas, business-intelligence, teradata, paraccel

I have recently shifted from Teradata to ParAccel and I use my BI DBMS with SAS environment. Teradata has this utility called `FastLoad` for loading large datasets fast and more efficiently. I often have to make use of this utility to transfer datasets from SAS libraries to Teradata. I would like to know if there's a similar utility/command/function for ParAccel as well. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ParAccel appears to be a vendor; if you have their software, did you check their documentation?  Also, you might want to re-word you question and ask directly about bulk-loading capabilities of ParAccel.  This really has nothing to do with either SAS or Teradata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, ParAccel does have a bulk loading utility and also has a ODBC module for SAS to load data directly. I would encourage you to reach out to ParAccel support!!.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the copy command

> psql $DATABASE -c "copy destination_table() from
>   'local' with parallel delimiter ',' truncatecolumns MAXERROR 100000"